# What is the most efficient way to get fill a ComboBox with all the registered file types (not just extensions)

Tags: c#, file, combobox, registry

What is the most efficient to fill a ComboBox with all the registered file types in Windows?

I want the full file type, not just the extension. I'm using VB 9 (VS2008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the file types are stored in the registry under the HKEY_CLASS_ROOT, which you could obtain using the Framework's [Registry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx).

Here's c# code to perform the task:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class FileAssoc
{
    public string Extension;
    public string Filetype;

    public FileAssoc(string fileext, string name)
    {
        Extension = fileext;
        Filetype = name;
    }
}

public static class EnumRegFiles
{
    public static List<FileAssoc> GetFileAssociations()
    {
        List<FileAssoc> result = new List<FileAssoc>();
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.ClassesRoot;

        String[] names = rk.GetSubKeyNames();
        foreach (string file in names)
        {
            if (file.StartsWith("."))
            {
                RegistryKey rkey = rk.OpenSubKey(file);
                object descKey = rkey.GetValue("");

                if (descKey != null)
                {
                    string desc = descKey.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc))
                    {
                        result.Add(new FileAssoc(file, desc));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joel, that's going to be a lot of entries and trying to find something in a combobox list of hundreds of items is going to end up as a really poor user experience. Other than that, the only way to get this information is to go through the registry, as Mitch says but it won't be simple code.

What are you trying to accomplish?

**Edit:** @Mitch Wheat, I know this was addressed to @Mark Brackett, but I couldn't resist the challenge. Using LINQ, your code can be written as:

```
public static IList GetFileAssociations()
{
    return Registry.ClassesRoot.GetSubKeyNames().Where(key => key.StartsWith(".")).Select(key =>
    {
        string description = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key).GetValue("") as string;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
        {
            return new { key, description };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }).Where(a => a != null).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The code is simple (and has been posted now - looks to be about 20 lines, and it could be cut down at least 50% or so), you didn't answer the question, and your post essentially boils down to "me, too!". That said, I didn't downvote it, just offering critiques. ;)

Comment: @Mark Brackett: if you think you can cut that code I posted down by 50%, I suggest you post an answer showing how to do so!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I know this was addressed to @Mark Brackett, but I couldn't resist the challenge. See the edit to my answer for a LINQ version.

Comment: @Scott Dorman: OK it's shorter, but is it easier to understand?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: That wasn't part of the original requirements. :) If you are familiar/comfortable with LINQ I would argue that it is as easy to understand as your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Collections;
internal static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a dictionary containing known file extensions and description from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>dictionary containing extensions and description.</returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAllRegisteredFileExtensions()
    {
        //get into the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
        RegistryKey root = Registry.ClassesRoot;

        //generic list to hold all the subkey names
        Dictionary<string, string> subKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //IEnumerator for enumerating through the subkeys
        IEnumerator enums = root.GetSubKeyNames().GetEnumerator();

        //make sure we still have values
        while (enums.MoveNext())
        {
            //all registered extensions start with a period (.) so
            //we need to check for that
            if (enums.Current.ToString().StartsWith("."))
                //valid extension so add it and the default description if it exists
                subKeys.Add(enums.Current.ToString(), Registry.GetValue(root.Name + "\\" + enums.Current.ToString(), "", "").ToString());
        }
        return subKeys;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but it's worth considering:  on many systems, that's *LOT* of items.  Perhaps a search or Listbox instead?